# FUIArray : can not return the correct number of array element

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I try to get the `Contacts.count` using FUIArray (FirebaseDatabaseUI).

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseDatabaseUI
import SwiftyJSON

class ChatVC: UIViewController, FUICollectionDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{


    var contactRef: FUIDataObservable!
    var Contacts : FUIArray!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        contactRef = Database.database().reference().child("club")
        Contacts = FUIArray(query: contactRef )
        print(Contacts.count)
        Contacts.observeQuery()

        Contacts.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

The club node has 2 Childs.

[image]

print(Contact.count) return 0.
What is wrong?

Comment: Are you authenticated and did you check the Firebase rules to ensure your app has access to that path? Do you need *FUIArray.init(query: query)*?

Comment: yes, user login and Firebase rules are fine. Do I need to do FUIArray.init(query: query)?

Comment: I believe the constructer may need the .init. Try it and see if it makes a difference. Unfortunately the FUIArray functions are not well documented (IMO)